# Execute .exe file using PHP

Tags: php, linux, windows, exe

I want to execute a .exe file using PHP. I am stuck with this because the PHP function should have to work any operation system. (Windows or Linux)

Actual thing what I want to do is, its a PHP system.if somehow the tomcat server get corrupted I have to give and option to user to execute tomcat installer using the system.Mainly the system will run on linux,but in some case it could be run in windows.

Can anyone help me to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Windows executables don't run on Linux (without something like Wine).

Comment: Is this file its executing also "myexecutable.exe" on linux? Or is the linux script going to poke another server to run the exe?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a system program from a php file the function `exec()` works on both a Windows server and a Linux server however you can't run .exe files on a linux server unless you use something like Wine.  Java is meant to be cross-platform so if you want to run a .jar on either Windows or Linux you might be able to.  Anyway, try using `exec()` and if you are getting any errors report them back and we can help you some more.

**Example**

```
<?php
    // Run ffmpeg command
    exec('ffmpeg  -itsoffset -4  -i test.avi -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 test.jpg');
```